# javascript--loop through json and add accumulative number to the end

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am new to javascript and I want to loop through json data and add accumulative number to the end of it.
Here is a sample dataset:

```
[{'a':123,'b':345,'c':{'b1':1,'b2':2,'b3':3}},  
 {'a':234,'b':456,'c':{'b1':2,'b2':4,'b3':6}},  
 {'a':345,'b':567,'c':{'b1':3,'b2':6,'b3':9}}]
```

And this is what I want to achieve:

```
[{'a':123,'b':345,'c':{'b1':1,'b2':2,'b3':3},'d':345+1+2+3},  
 {'a':234,'b':456,'c':{'b1':2,'b2':4,'b3':6},'d':456+2+4+6},  
 {'a':345,'b':567,'c':{'b1':3,'b2':6,'b3':9},'d':567+3+6+9}]
```

Comment: Did you try a forEach() function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to iterate the array, and generate new objects that contain the property `d`. For each object in the array, use [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Basic_assignment) with [rest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Rest_in_Object_Destructuring) to assign `a` value to a property, and the rest of the properties to an object (named `rest` in this case).

Create a new object, using `a` and `rest` (by [spreading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Rest_in_Object_Destructuring) it), and add the `d` property, which is the sum of all `rest` properties.

To sum object properties recursively I've added the `sumProps` method. The function uses [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) to get an array of values. Then it iterates an sum them using [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce). Unless a value is an object, in which case we run it through `sumProps` again.

```js
const data = [
 {'a':123,'b':345,'c':{'b1':1,'b2':2,'b3':3}},
 {'a':234,'b':456,'c':{'b1':2,'b2':4,'b3':6}},
 {'a':345,'b':567,'c':{'b1':3,'b2':6,'b3':9}}
];

const sumProps = (o) =>
  Object.values(o) // get the values of an object
    .reduce((r, v) => // iterate the values
      r + (typeof v === 'object' ? sumProps(v) : v) // add the values to the previous sum, and if the values are an object sum it recursively
    , 0);

// iterate the objects with map
const result = data.map(({ a, ...rest }) => { // destructure a, and an object of all other params
  return ({ // combine them back to an object
    a,
    ...rest, // spread the rest object
    d: sumProps(rest) // get the sum of the rest, and assign to d
  });
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response, but because I am really new to the js, i have no idea what does the code mean, for example: const sumProps = (o) =>
  Object.values(o)
    .reduce((r, v) => 
      r + (typeof v === 'object' ? sumProps(v) : v)
    , 0); Can you please explain to me what does it do or maybe some reference to it? Thank you so mucj!

Comment: I've included an explanation and links to mdn articles about the method used. Enjoy :)

Comment: You are the best! :)

Comment: Elegant answer @Ori Drori